# Struts2 Session cluster - Issue with non serialized object - when TokenSessionInterceptor is used(2.3.16) version

Tags: struts2, session-management, struts2-interceptors

I am trying to configure, Session clustering for one of my `struts2` based application, but it fails if I use `TokenSessionInterceptor` in application. Following error is observed in logs when session persistence is in progress.

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1164)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceMap.writeObject(ReferenceMap.java:595)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:945)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1469)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
        at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1001)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:945)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1469)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
        at org.apache.jsp.showSession_jsp._jspService(showSession_jsp.java:178)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult.doExecute(ServletDispatcherResult.java:164)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:371)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:275)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:139)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.TokenSessionStoreInterceptor.handleValidToken(TokenSessionStoreInterceptor.java:169)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.TokenSessionStoreInterceptor.handleToken(TokenSessionStoreInterceptor.java:116)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.TokenInterceptor.doIntercept(TokenInterceptor.java:142)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I have seen reference for similar issue [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4028), which mentions about fixing this issue, but issue still exists when used version 2.3.16.

Let me know if anyone has solution for it.

Thanks

Comment: It's fixed in version 2.3.15.

Comment: I am using upgraded version i.e. 2.3.16, I see problem not completely fixed.

Comment: It must be something else - it's another inquiry with the same stacktrace